# jQuery drop-down bug when used in my rails 3 app but works outside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery but I'm trying to learn. I'm working with a drop down button that works just fine in jsfiddle. However, when I try it in my rails 3 app, it won't work. (nothing drops down when you click the link). working jsifiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/32/

If I remove the line `$(".menu").fixedMenu();` and add it into the html like this it works. I'm stumped as to why its not working unless I remove the `$(".menu").fixedMenu();` line

NOT working

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.fixedMenu = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      var menu = $(this);
        $("html").click(function() {
        menu.find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');
      });
      menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        //check whether the particular link has a dropdown
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('single-link') && !$(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
          //hiding drop down menu when it is clicked again
          if ($(this).parent().hasClass('drop-down')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('drop-down');
          }
          else {
            //displaying the drop down menu
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');
            $(this).parent().addClass('drop-down');
          }
        }
        else {
          //hiding the drop down menu when some other link is clicked
          $(this).parent().parent().find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');

      }
      })
    });
  }
  $(".menu").fixedMenu();
  })(jQuery);
```

Working

html

```
<script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('.menu').fixedMenu();
        });
        </script>
```

js

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.fixedMenu = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      var menu = $(this);
        $("html").click(function() {
        menu.find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');
      });
      menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        //check whether the particular link has a dropdown
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('single-link') && !$(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
          //hiding drop down menu when it is clicked again
          if ($(this).parent().hasClass('drop-down')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('drop-down');
          }
          else {
            //displaying the drop down menu
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');
            $(this).parent().addClass('drop-down');
          }
        }
        else {
          //hiding the drop down menu when some other link is clicked
          $(this).parent().parent().find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');

      }
      })
    });
  }
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you produce a shorter test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
$(".menu").fixedMenu();
```

cannot be executed until the page has been loaded and the DOM is fully in place.

Thus, it works when you surround it with `$(document).ready()` and doesn't work when you directly executed it in your startup JS.  When it's executed before the DOM is ready, the DOM object `$(".menu")` can't be found so it does nothing.

It works in the jsFiddle because ALL your code is wrapped in an onload handler (per the settings in the upper left of the jsFiddle).

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work still, I'm not sure it needed the extra markup inside, for some reaons it doesn't jive together

Comment: I think you should put the calling of fixedMenu, outside the declaration of this extension, this whole part 
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu").fixedMenu();
  });

Comment: It's intended to be after the definition of the fixedMenu jQuery extension is done, but still inside the very outer function scope, though there is no reason it needs to be in the outer function scope.